# Hide formulas in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Ok here is the problem. I have the following Code:

```
$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $excel->load($template);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

//filling up the sheet with tons of info

$sheet->getProtection()->setPassword('YouWishUKnew');
$sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

it loads the template stored in `$template` (duh) and populates it with data.

Here is the problem. The template had some formulas locked, as in the cells weren't even selectable.

After the re-population the lock is gone (so i set it up again, no problem here) but now when I open the re-populated sheet I can see all the formulas!

**My question is:** 
Is there a way to lock the cells (make them unselectable) or hide the formulas (like the excel option in Format Cells -> Protection -> Hidden)?

PS: I checked the other questions and didn't find anything to answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use

```
$sheet->getStyle('C'.$riga)
      ->getProtection()
      ->setHidden(
          PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_PROTECTED
      );
```

let me know if this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Gotrekk answer, in order to make it work, you need to have protection enabled for the active sheet. So, the complete answer would be:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D3:AS'.$maxRows)
    ->getProtection()
    ->setHidden(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_PROTECTED);
```